# What was the first Christmas themed Lego set?

Tags: sets, history

For as long as I can remember Lego has been making Special Christmas themed sets every year. Advent calendars, [Winter village](http://www.legobrickguy.com/blog/2016/11/11/a-lego-home-for-the-holidays-a-history-of-legos-winter-village) sets, Christmas trains, and on and on.
What was the first Christmas themed Lego set?

Answer (score 9):

[image]

I don't know whether this quite qualifies as a set, but there is a LEGO promotional Christmas box from 1964 [listed on bricklink](https://store.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=promo1964d-1)

Comment: Nice find! Brickset doesn't list this set so I didn't see it come by in my search.

Comment: Are they Lego bricks? As in: can you plug them to other classic bricks? Or are those plain flat dominos that you can't attach to anything?

Comment: @Cœur I not quite sure, but the description on bricklink says "outer box have storage wear inner boxes and parts still new" so it sounds like they are LEGO bricks.

Answer (score 8):

There have been Christmas-themed sets for a long time, for example set [246-2 Santa and Sleigh](https://brickset.com/sets/246-2/Santa-and-Sleigh) from 1977.

[image]

Scrolling through all LEGO sets on Brickset, starting from 1949, shows that this is also the first set in their records that is Christmas themed, together with the (likely unreleased) two Santas set 245-2.